# Reference Subpoints of Lemma

Tags: cross-referencing, enumerate, theorems

I have Lemmata consisting of several subpoints (basically a collection of similar formulas) and I want to reference these subpoints in text by "Lemma 1 (1)".

So far my code looks like this:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\usepackage{hyperref}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}


\begin{document}
   \begin{lemma}\label{lemma}
      This is a collection of formulas
      \begin{enumerate}
          \item Equation 1 \label{sublemmaOne}
          \item Equation 2
      \end{enumerate}
  \end{lemma}

 A reference to the first item of the lemma \autoref{lemma}(\ref{sublemmaOne}).

\end{document}
```

This works somehow and I can even make a macro :

```
\newcommand{\refSublemmaOne}{\autoref{lemma}(\ref{sublemmaOne})}
```

However, I see two goals for improvement

- I would prefer it if there were a single hyperref link instead of two close to each other
- I would prefer to somehow use the usual \autoref{mylabel} syntax so on referencing I do not have to care whether I reference a normal lemma or a subpoint.

I am both open to suggestions that directly address the referencing and to ones to structure the lemma differently than by using enumerate if it is still a lemma with subpoints and that helps to solve the referencing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using the `enumitem` package you can set the format of the references with the option `ref=format`, see [the enumitem manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf) page 3. In the example below the format is set to

`\thelemma (\arabic*)`

which prints `\the` value of the `lemma` counter followed by `(` and the `\arabic` representation of the `*` (=current enumerate) counter followed by `)`.

Code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\usepackage{hyperref}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}


\begin{document}
   \begin{lemma}
   \label{mylemma}
      This is a collection of formulas
      \begin{enumerate}[ref=\thelemma (\arabic*)]
          \item Equation 1 \label{sublemmaOne}
          \item Equation 2 \label{sublemmaTwo}
      \end{enumerate}
  \end{lemma}

 A reference to the first item of the lemma \ref{sublemmaOne} or the second item \ref{sublemmaTwo}.

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]